# How can I retrieve code from another html page using js & jquery, onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I've noticed that when using the following code for the purposes detailed in the title, that code from settings.html appears, then disappears almost instantaneously.

Javascript:

```
function load() {
    $("#paste").load("settings.html");
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="" onclick="load();">Settings</a>
<div id="paste"></div>
```

However when using the following javascript/jquery instead, the browser freezes. (And the content does not load at all)

```
function load() {
  for (i = 0; i < 1;) {
    $("#paste").load("settings.html");
  }
}
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Try changing `<a href="" onclick="load();">` to `<a href="#" onclick="load();">`. And your for loop `for (i = 0; i < 1;)` isn't valid since you forgot the third argument

Comment: Don't make it an infinite loop?

Comment: @j08691 it's valid, it's just infinite since `i` never increments

Comment: @SterlingArcher I don't consider an infinite loop valid here, sorry

Comment: I'd like for the content from settings.html to appear forever (not appear and  disappear almost instantaneously after clicking) I was hoping an indefinite loop would do this. It seems not. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `onclick="load(); return false;"` will work.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat With no loop?

Comment: @Milomotal Yes!

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Out of curiosity, why does this work?

Comment: A famous line in our industry. *It works? Don't touch it!* :p

Comment: @Milomotal Well, `return false` is preventing the default behaviour of `<a>` tag, ie it prevents browser from changing it's `window.location.href`

Comment: A better option here is to not use a link, since it's not the job of an anchor tag to act like a button

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Code

```
function load() {
    $("#paste").load("settings.html");
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="load();">Settings</a>
<div id="paste"></div>
```